# Angular 6 Multiple levels of RoutingModule

Tags: angular, routes, angular6, angular2-routing, angular-module

I am building a large angular 6 app. I have already built one level of routing:

Here is my `app-routing.module.ts`:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { AComponent } from './a/a.component';
import { BComponent  } from './b/b.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/a', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'a', component: AComponent },
  { path: 'b', component: BComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [ RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: true }) ],
  exports: [ RouterModule ]
})

export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

In `a/a.component.html`, `A1Component` is used:

```
<a1></a1>
```

I want to have a routing for another two components in `A1Component`: `A1xComponent` and `A1yComponent`.

How can I do this without changing anything in `app-routing.module.ts`?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Why can't you add the two additional routes to the routing module?

Comment: @Pike96 According to me two way to do this one is add `children: A1xComponent` in your `A1Component` or second one is `feature module` using lazy loading.

Comment: @Abhishek Thank you! I end up giving up routing and using component interaction and event emitter